# Excel formula to display what data elements are present, is concatenate the right approach?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with 12K+ names with various columns and want to be able to see which data elements are "true" for each name.

Example file

| Last Name | First Name | DOB | XYZ(not required) | EmployeeID | SSN | Financial Account ID | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | John | Y |  |  | Y |  | Y |
| Smith | John |  |  | Y | Y |  | Y |
| Smith | Jayne | Y |  |  |  | Y |  |
| Rock | Dwayne |  |  | Y |  | Y | Y |
| Foster | Jane |  |  | Y |  |  |  |

I want to be able to create a column that outputs what data elements are present, like so:

| Last Name | First Name | Data Element | DOB | XYZ(not required) | EmployeeID | SSN | Financial Account ID | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | John | DOB, SSN, Address | Y |  |  | Y |  | Y |
| Smith | John | EmployeeID, SSN, Address |  |  | Y | Y |  | Y |
| Smith | Jayne | DOB, Financial Account ID | Y |  |  |  | Y |  |
| Rock | Dwayne | EmployeeID, Financial Account ID, Address |  |  | Y |  | Y | Y |
| Foster | Jane | EmployeeID |  |  | Y |  |  |  |

What formula could I use to list out the true data elements? Could I use a concatenate to display only the top level value of column, as that function will skip fields that are blank..

Answer (score 0):

If you have the FILTER and TEXTJOIN functions available you could use a formula like this.

This formula assumes original data in A1:G6, and the formula is put in H2 and copied down.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, FILTER($C$1:$G$1, C2:G2="Y"))
```

Those functions are available in Excel 365 and later versions of Excel

Comment: Thank you! that gets me what I need but due to my oversight in the initial question to simplify it, I forgot to mention that the file also contains columns not required in between the columns that are required. 

like there could be consecutive columns of needed data elements and then some non-essential data columns, then a required column

Comment: Can you update your question to show the further requirements?

Comment: Yup, updated! thanks.